# Python ctypes, pass c_void_p as an out parameter to c function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm writing a Python module that wraps some C++ code. I used to use this function to pass a pointer from C++ to Python (the pointer would be freed by a different function

```cpp
DLLEXPORT void* run(double input1, double input2)
```

I've added error return codes so my new function looks like

```cpp
DLLEXPORT int run(double input1, double input2, void* output)
```

But now I can't seem to get the value of the pointer, in Python I set up the function with ctypes as follows

```py
from ctypes import *
mydll = cdll.mydll

mydll.run.argtypes = [c_double, # input 1
                      c_double, # input 2
                      c_void_p] # output pointer
mydll.run.restype  = c_int
```

Then I use the function by creating a new void pointer in Python and passing it to the dll function

```py
p = c_void_p()

retval = mydll.run(1.2, 3.4, p)

print p
```

After running this code I am left with `p` equal to `c_void_p(None)`.

Passing this pointer to other functions causes illegal access exceptions at address 0x0, so I don't think it is being updated.

I am expected some address to populate `p` after execution. I am missing something with ctypes? I can create a double array by allocating `(c_double * 10)()` and pass that to c function to be written to, why can't I pass a void pointer for the same purpose?

Comment: If `run` expects a `void **` it should be typed as such. In this case pass `byref(p)` as the argument in Python. In C or C++ you dereference the pointer to store the value, e.g.  `*output = some_address`.

Comment: @eryksun wow, my whole problem was `run` **not** expecting `void **`. simple fix, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As eryksun's comment points out, for `void*` to be an output parameter, it should be `void**`:

```
# DLLEXPORT int run(double input1, double input2, void** output)

from ctypes import *
mydll = cdll.mydll

mydll.run.argtypes = [c_double, # input 1
                      c_double, # input 2
                      POINTER(c_void_p)] # output pointer
mydll.run.restype  = c_int

p = c_void_p()
retval = mydll.run(1.2,3.4,byref(p))

print p.contents
```