# casting ctypes c_void_p to C output parameter

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes, out

first I know about [Python ctypes, pass c_void_p as an out parameter to c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813272/python-ctypes-pass-c-void-p-as-an-out-parameter-to-c-function) and their suggested solution BUT I was not able to make it work, with their answer. My Problem is similar anyways...

I have a C funtion i want to Wrap with Python using ctypes. It Accepts

```
error_t foo(int a,void ** bar)
```

with `bar` as an output parameter.

My Python ctypes looks like described in the linked thread:

```
bar = c_void_p()
foo(guids, byref(bar))
```

I Do NOT know what i do wrong or different... am kinda clueless...

The output for the type of `bar` always just displays:

`c_void_p(None)`

thanks for any help or ideas...

Comment: It is recommended to use cffi instead of ctypes. It provides a much easier interface. So if you are not bound to ctypes, take a look: https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#working-with-pointers-structures-and-arrays

Comment: What were you expecting the output to be? In the linked question, the correct answer prints an attribute (`contents`) of the pointer; Is something to this effect your goal?

Comment: I would expect it to have a value, more specific a handle for identification... I edited the Question to make that more clear. @jackw11111

will take a look at it, tanks.@Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
import os
file=open("/tmp/1.c","w")
# you didn't provide the implementation of foo (why?) so i needed to write it myself
file.write(
"typedef int error_t;"
"error_t foo(int a,void ** bar) {"
"       *bar = a;"
"       return a * 2;"
"}"
)
file.close()
os.system("gcc -Wno-int-conversion -shared -o /tmp/lib1.so.1 /tmp/1.c")

import ctypes
lib1 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/tmp/lib1.so.1")
guids = 1000

# the code you provided us
bar = ctypes.c_void_p()
ret = lib1.foo(guids, ctypes.byref(bar))
# end of the code you provided us

print("foo(" + str(guids) + ", " + str(ctypes.byref(bar)) + ") = " + str(ret))
print("And bar has the value: " +  str(bar));
```

Prints out:

```
foo(1000, <cparam 'P' (0x7ffa3414ee68)>) = 2000
And bar has the value: c_void_p(1000)
```

The script compiles to a shared library a simple C program:

```
typedef int error_t;
error_t foo(int a,void ** bar) {
       *bar = a;
       return a * 2;
}
```

Then runs the function using ctypes from python.
As expected calling `foo(1000, ...)` returned `2000` and set the value of `void *bar` to `1000`. So the python call you do is ok, inspect the function. Probably your `foo()` set's the value of `bar` to `NULL`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the detaileld answer!
I did not provide the code of foo beacause it is part of a .so/.dll and I Only have access to the header file.
Never the less I have to say that the function seems to be working just fine beacause calls from C++ as well as calls from our C# Wrapper do work pretty well...

snippet from the C# Wrapper:


`IntPtr handle= IntPtr.Zero;
                string guid = guidList[1];
                errorCode = OpenCamera(guid, out handle);`

@Kamil Cuk

Comment: Fixed it with some help of my colleague  :)

but you were right, the problem was within the .dll. The first parameter was faulty. and the function returned error_t = 0 even if it actually failed. Thanks anyways!